# Rails destroy nested entries.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have my app set up as follows:

-Generated scaffolds for Categories and Products.

-Products belongs_to Categories and Categories has_many Products.

I am currently able to delete/remove an individual category, however the products within that category remain in the db. How would I be able to delete a category as well as all products contained within only that specific category?

Currently my category controller looks as follows:

```
def destroy
@Category = Category.find(params[:id])
@Category.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to (:back) }
  format.json { head :ok }
end
```

end

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do have a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need inside category.rb

```
has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
```